# Add link to an image php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, hyperlink

My WordPress theme has a presentation page template with full screen scrolling images. I'd like to add a separate link to each image. How would I do that?

```
            <?php } else if ($presentation_type == 'image'){ ?>
                    <div class="section" data-id="<?php echo $presentation_name; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $presentation_image; ?>);" data-nav-color="<?php echo $presentation_style; ?>">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where would you like the link? wrapping the scrolling image?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have no dynamic code in the `<div />` HTML5 allows you to simply wrap it with and `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo $presentation_image; ?>">
    <div class="section" data-id="<?php echo $presentation_name; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $presentation_image; ?>);" data-nav-color="<?php echo $presentation_style; ?>">

    ...

    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the data- attribute and add the URL to the current div using data-url and using JavaScript to open the link like so:

```
<div class="section" data-id="<?php echo $presentation_name; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $presentation_image; ?>);" data-nav-color="<?php echo $presentation_style; ?>" data-url="<?php echo $url; ?>">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVdoaZ